# Toast - принудительный перенос строки

Tags: android, android-toast

Есть код

```
 Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Найдено элементов: " + String.valueOf(TemVsego)  +
                            ". Записей в активном курсоре: " + String.valueOf(ZapiseyCursor), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

Я хочу сделать перенос строки перед ". Записей в активном курсоре: ".
пытался ставить "\n" - не работает
помню, что в Delphi писал +chr(13)+.
здесь это тоже не проходит.
как поступить?

Comment: `"\n"` должно работать. покажите, как у вас не работает

Answer (score 0):

Для этого вам понадобиться написать свой custom toast

```
Context context=getApplicationContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();

        View customToastroot =inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_TOAST_LAYOUT, null);

        Toast customtoast=new Toast(context);

        customtoast.setView(customToastroot);
        customtoast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL,0, 0);
        customtoast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        customtoast.show();
```

Comment: спасибо. попробую

Answer (score 0):

Для таких целей, как уже было замечено, используют `\n`.

Для вас код может выглядеть так:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
              "Найдено елементов - " + String.valueOf(TemVsego) + ".\n" + 
              "Записей в активном курсоре - " + String.valueOf(ZapiseyCursor) + ".", 
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем откликнувшимся. Немного доработал код. Тему можно закрыть.

```js
    public void showToast() {
        Toast toast3 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Найдено элементов- " + String.valueOf(TemVsego) + ".\n" +
                        "Записей в активном курсоре: " + String.valueOf(ZapiseyCursor) +".\n" +
                        "Тема: " + TablNazvAktivTemi, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        toast3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        LinearLayout toastContainer = (LinearLayout) toast3.getView();
        ImageView catImageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        catImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.znak1);
        toastContainer.addView(catImageView, 0);
        toast3.show();
    }
```